# Space requirements for a ROS mirror

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could anyone give me an idea what the HD space requirements currently are for mirroring the ROS repository? We are currently considering setting up a mirror and looking at the server requirements.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9170/space-requirements-for-a-ros-mirror/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently mirroring all debs (x86 & x86-64) for Hardy through Maverick. This is using 33GB of space.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-23**:
FYI, that should be both arch's, not source.

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2011-02-23**:
Is that for just one architecture -- or for both but not source? My copy of HJKLM:{x86,x86_64} comes to 246 GB. Edit: Turns out apt-mirror's "autoclean" wasn't doing anything. Added explicit "clean" lines and switched to packages.ros.org, now it's 24 GB for everything.